# CSSTransitionGroup with single custom component

Tags: reactjs

Can't get `CSSTransitionGroup` to work with my custom component.

Here is the code:

```
import {CSSTransitionGroup} from 'react-transition-group'

...

// in render():

  <CSSTransitionGroup
    transitionName='container'
    transitionEnterTimeout={500}
    transitionLeaveTimeout={300}
  >
    <MyComponent />
  </CSSTransitionGroup>
```

I see that `CSSTransitionGroup` has added a `span` with my component inside, but no classes on it. `MyComponent` render() method returns `null` or `<div />` (if `window.innerWidth < 960`). So I can see content disappearing and showing on window resize, but no classes from `CSSTransitionGroup`.

Please help

Comment: Have you tried adding a 'key'? The README says "You must provide the key attribute for all children of CSSTransitionGroup, even when only rendering a single item"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CSSTransitionGroup manages the animation of its child components when they mount or unmount from the component tree. Since the logic that controls the contents of `MyComponent` is *inside* of that component, CSSTransitionGroup can't see it and won't manage it, because `<MyComponent />` mounts and stays mounted.

For CSSTransitionGroup to work the way you want, you need to either put it inside of `MyComponent` so that it manages the `<div />` that you want to animate, or you need to directly mount and unmount `<MyComponent />`.

In other words, the elements/components that you want CSSTransitionGroup to control need to be *direct children* of the CSSTransitionGroup component, and mount and unmount within it, otherwise it won't work.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [React-Anime-Manager](https://github.com/perymimon/React-Anime-Manager) will work better for you

```
import {useAnimeManager} from '@perymimon/react-anime-manager'
import {useState} from "react";

function ShowHide() {
    const [show, setShow] = useState(true);
    const {item: flag, phase, done} = useAnimeManager(show, {oneAtATime: true});

    useEffect(_ => {
        setTimeout(_ => setShow(false) , 500)
    }, [show])


    /**-> because there is no element when flag == false. `done` must called expliclty to guide `useAnimeManager` continue with the states flow and show the `true` value when it arrive */
    if (!flag) done()

    return  flag && <MyComponent className="container" />
}
```